# Is the pinhole camera model appropriate for modelling a real camera?

Tags: computer-vision, modelling

I am developing a computer vision system, using the [pinhole camera model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model). Is this an appropriate model to use for a real camera? I know that lenses and such will distort the image, my main questions are: for a cheap webcam (which I plan to use), what are the distorting effects of lenses and having a finite sized camera, are they noticeable to throw off results (lets say a rough tolerance of placing an object 5cm away from its actual position), and how can this be corrected for? Apologies if this speaks too much about physical hardware for computer science.